# Pandas Python: Add column that counts IDs per Product

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a column to my dataframe that tells me the number of a product per group.
My dataframe looks like this:

```
ID    Product  Time
6578  X        ...
6574  Y
6439  X
6543  Y
6756  X
6756  X
```

What I want as an output is this:

```
ID    Product   Number_of_ID_per_Product  Time
6578  X         1                         ...
6574  Y         1
6439  X         2
6543  Y         2
6756  X         3
6756  X         4
```

I tried

```
df['ID_Number_per_Part']=vormessen.groupby(['Product'])['ID'].count()
```

which gives me only NaN values.

Comment: Use `vormessen.groupby('Product')['ID'].cumcount().add(1)`

Answer (score 0):

this can be done using group by statement (a concept very widely used in SQL)

```
df[0].groupyby(1: name of the field to group by with)(2: aggregated fields).([3: type of aggregation].()
```

In your case it will be:

0. Vormasseen
1. Product
2. ID
3. Count

Similarly, you can do the same for avg, max, min, etc.